# Blocking apache resource direct access but let it download as a link

Tags: apache, hyperlink, resources, blocking

I have a file that I want to be able to download from a page so I want it to be accessible by a link, but I want that the same URL isn't reachable by direct link for example putting it in the browser address bar.

I tried deny all in .htaccess but that didn't let me to access it via link.

Is there a way to let access to a resource only via link?

Comment: The only way to do it reliably is to require some kind of authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below rule,

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
allow from localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect "Referer" header and deny access if it is not from your web site:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Referer} !^http://example.com
RewriteRule link-only.html - [F]
```